# What is the best algorithm for Hindley Milner type inference when one wants to optimize for error messages

Tags: type-inference, hindley-milner

I want to implement Hindley-Milner type inference but as a non-academic person that doesn't know type theory at all, I'm getting a bit overwhelmed by all the different algorithms and their properties, the dependencies of papers on papers and all the new concepts I have to learn.

I'm looking for an algorithm or a few algorithms that stand out in terms of the error messages it can generate ([Something that Algorithm W and Algorithm M are supposedly not very good at](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-2002/2002-031.pdf)).

Can anyone point me to any helpful resources on this, or explain to me what I should be looking for in an algorithm to find out if it will be good for generating error messages, or both?

Note: It would be nice if it can support higher kinded types, but it's not an immediate requirement.